# how to set up permission of user in Sharepoint so they can see only images that they have permission?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am creating SharePoint web page. There are more than 70 document gallery which hold the reports. I need to create a webpage where I will put 70 different images once user click on the image it will take it to document gallery.

We have AD directory for the permission. How can i set up page where if i have 70 different images on web page but if user have permission to view number 5 gallery user can see only number 5 image on page not other 69 images. IF some user have 10 permission to view 10 different gallery he can see 10 images. Any idea would be great. I am using Sharepoint 2013 online.

Answer (score 1):

Use **audience targeting**

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293

you may have to use 70 different image viewer webparts for 70 different images , then set audience targeting for each webpart.